# Tensorflow(python):"ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to implement a neural network with a single hidden layer with my own set of images, but I am getting this error when I run the code;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnist_tf.py", line 128, in <module>
    test_x, test_y = get_test(M)
  File "mnist_tf.py", line 61, in get_test
    batch_xs = np.vstack((batch_xs, ((array(M[test_k[k]])[:])/255.)  ))
  File "/home/user/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 288, in hstack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

My image data(mat file) contains the following format;

there are 10 training and test sets

```
train0  70x784 uint8
test0   26x784 uint8
train1  70x784 uint8
test1   55x784 uint8
train2  70x784 uint8
test2   8x784 uint8
...
```

The code that I am using can be found in [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~guerzhoy/321/proj3/mnist_tf.py). Only thing that I changed is the input file, I gave my image dataset as a mat file instead of 'mnist_all.mat'. The error happens at line 61 in the get_test() function;

```
 batch_xs = np.vstack((batch_xs, ((array(M[test_k[k]])[:])/255.)  ))
```

I couldn't quite understand what `'((array(M[test_k[k]])[:])/255.)'` this part is doing. I know that there is a concatenation  problem with respect to array dimensions however I can't solve it.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1: 
this is my dataset;

```
('M[test0] = ', array([[ array([[180, 111, 108, ..., 128, 149, 147],

       [249, 160, 192, ...,  88, 119, 185],

       [166, 164,  60, ...,  28,  73,  59],
       ..., 
       [  5,   8,   4, ...,  82, 101, 123],

       [ 14,  14,  14, ..., 166, 166, 170],

       [ 62,  42,  73, ...,   3,   6,  25]], dtype=uint8)]], dtype=object))
```

and this is mnist_all dataset;

```
('M[test0] = ', array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],

       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],

       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ..., 
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],

       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],

       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8))
```

Comment: I think you should do `from numpy import *` at the beginning of the code which I don't like very much. Instead, you can replace `array` with `np.array` which is better. They are just slicing the array and dividing it by 255, something like a normalization

Comment: Thanks for your comment @kmario23. I replaced array at line 61 with np.array but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Ok, the original code uses `vstack` and you're using `hstack`. They're different operations. So, please check for the shapes of `batch_xs`, `M[test_k[k]]` and make sure they are compatible

Comment: Thanks again @kmario23 yes, you are right it should be vstack I edited the question.  When I check the shapes; batch_xs = (0, 784) and M[test_k[k]] = (1, 1). The shapes are different that's why I am getting the error right?

Comment: by the way I added another information about the datasets could you please also check it?